# Activate motor on speaker sound using speaker wire

Tags: arduino, current, switches

I have a mission: I want to put the board of a Google Home Mini inside the Nabaztag Smart Rabbit, an old iot device that doesn't work anymore because they shutdown the server.

Nabaztag has two motorized ears and some lights: I want to move the ears when Google Home Mini reproduce a sound. How can I detect the passage of current on the speaker wire (with arduino maybe?) so I can activate ears and lights?

Comment: Will both the Mini and the Smart Rabbit be powered off of the same supply?  What is the voltage available? What is the current draw on the motors and lights?

Comment: an optocoupler should make it easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a simple AC signal voltage detection circuit like this one that I designed many years ago: -

[image]

V2 is the audio line but you should be able to get away with a small current transformer with one of the speaker wires inserted through it.

C2 gets rapidly charged when a signal is detected and by making C2 bigger (say) 10 uF you can keep the LED lit for several seconds. I don't know what interface circuit you require so this is about as much help as I can give right now.